# jQuery First Item for Each ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two seperate lists and each of the list should add class active. Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

JavaSript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^='list'] .item").first().addClass("active");
});
```

As you can see only the #list1's first item getting the active class. How can i achive give the both list's first item active class.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iCromwell/rkvzhebd/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping over the parent, and then target first `.item`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^='list']").each(function(){
       $(this).find('.item').first().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkvzhebd/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through the list, the way you are approaching it, the class objects are being stacked in one selection list, and the `first()` is setting class to the first one only:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^='list']").each(function(){
            $(this).find('.item').first().addClass("active");
        })
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rkvzhebd/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `first-child` filter, such as:

```
$("ul li:first-child").addClass("active");
```

Comment: I think should be be specific for:  `$('ul[id^="list"] li:first-child').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 1):

`:first` or `.first()` looks for first element in the matched set. So, that is functioning correctly. While in your case you need to target all the first child elements in the matched parents.

Use `:first-child` pseudoselector instead:

```js
$('[id^="list"] .item:first-child').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`first()` filter your result and return only first element - so only one element is selected. Use `:first-child` pseudo selector to achieve result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id^='list'] .item:first-child").addClass("active");
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("[id^='list'] .item:first-child").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("[id^='list']").find('.item:first').addClass("active");`

#### Explanation:

- `$("[id^='list']")` will return a list of `ul`s
- Then in this list, you can search using `.find`. Since you only need first element, add `:first` selector
- Add class to all elements fetched

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^='list']").find('.item:first').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li class="item">Object 1</li>
  <li class="item">Object 2</li>
  <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
  <li class="item">Object 1</li>
  <li class="item">Object 2</li>
  <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="list"]').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.item').first().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li class="item">Object 1</li>
    <li class="item">Object 2</li>
    <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-child` selector on each ul instead of `id^=list`

```js
$("ul li:first-child").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li class="item">Object 1</li>
  <li class="item">Object 2</li>
  <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
  <li class="item">Object 1</li>
  <li class="item">Object 2</li>
  <li class="item">Object 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with javascript you can do it like this,

Here, we are selecting both the list ul tag `$("[id^='list']")` which returns an array of both list now we can iterate over the array using jquery `each()` tag which call the function sent in argument with the this attribute pointing to the each item in the array.

Now, we can add the class .active by simply doing `$(this).find('item').first().addclass('active');`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="list"]').each(function(){
       $(this).find('.item').first().addClass('active');
    });
   });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
        <li class="item">Object 1</li>
        <li class="item">Object 2</li>
        <li class="item">Object 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li class="item">Object 1</li>
        <li class="item">Object 2</li>
        <li class="item">Object 3</li>
    </ul>
```

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadirlaskar/rkvzhebd/9/)

The whole thing can be done without javascript and using only css as follows

```css
ul[id^='list'] :first-child {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
    <ul id="list1">
        <li class="item">Object 1</li>
        <li class="item">Object 2</li>
        <li class="item">Object 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li class="item">Object 1</li>
        <li class="item">Object 2</li>
        <li class="item">Object 3</li>
    </ul>
```

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadirlaskar/w770h2xj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul[id^='list'] :first-child").addClass("active");
});
```

Fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mxautp3L/